# Entity Framework 6 error - no key defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I'm getting the following error in the compiler:

```
MySite.DAL.ContentArticleSubdivision: : EntityType 'ContentArticleSubdivision' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ContentArticleSubdivision: EntityType: EntitySet 'ContentArticleSubdivision' is based on type 'ContentArticleSubdivision' that has no keys defined.
```

however, I've defined ContentArticleSubdivision like this:

```
public partial class ContentArticleSubdivision
{
    public long ContentArticleId { get; set; }
    public int SubdivisionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subdivision> Subdivisions { get; set; }
}
```

where ContentArticleId is a Foreign Key back to 'ContentArticle', which is defined starting like this:

```
public partial class ContentArticle
{
    [KeyAttribute] /* needed for FreeTextSearch class - if used */
    public long Id { get; set; }
```

My understanding is since I've named my Foreign Key property in the form `<LinkedEntityTypeName><PrimaryKeyField>`, i.e. I have the property ContentArticleId, where this links to 'Id' as defined in the 'ContentArticle' model, EF will understand that ContentArticleId should be the Foreign Key.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is there a primary key on the subdivision table?

Comment: No, there wasn't - that turned out to be the issue.  I'd originally created this as a link table that just contained two foreign keys for the tables it was linking.  Adding a primary key fixed it.  If you add this as an answer I'll mark it as correct, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity requires a primary key on any table, adding one to the specific table mentioned in the error should resolve the issue.